# Print dynamic Excel page with changing content

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with two worksheets.
On the **first one I have a "form"** and on the **second all the data in a table**.

What I have done is that on the first sheet I change an **ID number**, then a function looks at the second sheet to find the ID number and then changes the data on the cells I've specified to those on the second page.
It is for paying company employees and there are currently **50 unique ID's**.

Is there a way to print the first sheet with different content in one click if possible? Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Are the **ID numbers** stored somewhere? Like in a range of cells.

Comment: Activate the worksheet that you want to print and then just use `ActiveSheet.Printout` and it will print one copy of the active sheet using the default printer.

Comment: @branislav-kollár
The ID numbers are stored on the far left of the second pages table. I use the function vlookup to search for the ID and then it pulls the data from that table.

Comment: @jlili-amen Won't this just print the current worksheet as it's seen? I want to print it many times each with the different data that will be changed automatically when changing an ID in the first page.

Comment: Whenever you change the ID on the first sheets, changes occur in the second and you want to print the second after each change takes place, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this `For each myCell in worksheets(2).range("A1:A50")...next myCell` to loop through all the stored cells with different ID's and put each of the value to the cell on the sheet 1.
This is what I mean

```
Sub PrintAll_IDs()
    For Each myCell In Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A50") 'range with stored ID's
        Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = myCell.value ' "A1" is the cell with ID that you change manually now
        Worksheets(1).PrintOut ' I'm not sure how to print using VBA, just showing the workflow
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That was exactly what i wanted to do and it worked perfectly! You saved me so much time having to change the value and print again and again!