# Printing dynamic value in Excel while changing content - Except blanks

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with 2 sheets: On the first one there's a form and, on the second one, a list with multiple bits of data. Using data from the second sheet, [I'm using this fabulous macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29532967/9154021), which I found on SO by Branislav Kollár to change and print fully completed forms.

```
Sub PrintAll_IDs()
For Each myCell In Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A50") 'range with stored ID's
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = myCell.value ' "A1" is the cell with ID that you change manually now
    Worksheets(1).PrintOut ' I'm not sure how to print using VBA, just showing the workflow
Next myCell 
End Sub
```

The thing is that for it to work you have to manually adjust the printing range (In this case, A1:A50) and I'd like it to be fully automatic, somenthing like: Read first value in column of data table and go on until no more data is found.

I tried adding "If" statements to terminate proccess if blank cells are found and also adding ".End(x1Down)" but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: That should be `xlDown` - the letter "l" as in "Lima" and not the number "1"...

Comment: My bad, just a typo when I wrote this question. Didn't work either with the actual l.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's a couple.

```
option explicit

Sub PrintAll_IDs()
    dim myCell  as range
    with Worksheets(2)
        'range with stored ID's
        For Each myCell In .Range(.cells(1, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup))
            ...
        Next myCell 
    end with
End Sub

Sub PrintAll_IDs()
    dim myCell  as range
    with Worksheets(2)
        'range with stored ID's
        For Each myCell In .Range("A:A").specialcells(xlcelltypeconstants, xlnumbers+xlTextValues)
            ...
        Next myCell 
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @jeeped! Got it with a little tweak to the original code using part of what you said: `Sub PrintAll_IDs()
    For Each myCell In Worksheets("2").Range("E2:E999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers + xlTextValues)
        Worksheets("1").Range("B2") = myCell.Value
        Worksheets("1").PrintOut
    Next myCell
End Sub`